# Rails has_many through with specific id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, has-many-through

I'm trying to create the following:

**Models**: User, Account, Transaction
**Logic**: User has many accounts. Accounts has many transactions. User has many transactions through accounts.

**MODELS**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :transactions, :through => :accounts
End

class Account < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :transactions
end

class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
end
```

**MIGRATIONS**

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :accounts do |t|
      t.string :account_id
      t.belongs_to :user, index:true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.string :account_id
      t.decimal :amount, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.belongs_to :account, index:true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm able to create accounts for User with the following code:

```
user = User.create(name: "John")
user.accounts.create(account_id: "123")
```

But when it comes to transactions, using the same logic:

```
user = User.create(name: "John")
user.accounts.create(account_id: "123")
accounts.transactions.create(account_id: "123", amount: 10)
```

I get an error

> NoMethodError: undefined method transactions for Account

Comment: Shouldn't it be a single `account` instead of `accounts` to create transactions for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.string :account_id
      t.belongs_to :account, index:true
    end
  end
end
```

belongs_to :account will create a column called account_id, but you already have account_id in the line above. change `t.string :account_id` to `t.string :account_name`.  In general, I only use _id for foreign keys.

Comment: That made the trick, now I am able to create transactions! I was under the impression that by adding the has_many_through relationship I would be able to use something like this: "user.transactions" which returns an empty array at the moment.

Comment: user.transactions should return the correct transactions.  Rails has a cache for the relationship transactions in the user instance and is not always aware of changes in the database.  if you use `user.transactions << transaction` to create the join table record it will know about it, if you use `Account.create` it will not know about it.  You can use `user.transactions.reload` to invalidate the cache and force a database read.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issue I have here,

In both Accounts and transaction you have a string column account_id. In transaction the foreign key to account will be account_id as well by default?

so you might have to keep a diff name for that.

And you are calling accounts.transactions, each account has many transactions, so transactions should be called on a single account object instead.(Accounts.last.transactions or such)

And I don't see accounts being defined anywhere(I am assuming you didn't post that part of the code.
)